# Stacking arrays of multi dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I can't really wrap my head around this... and I'm not sure if stacking is the right term to use here.

```
A.shape = (28,28,1)
B.shape = (28,28,1)
```

If I want to merge/add/stack these arrays to this format:

```
C.shape = (2,28,28,1)
```

How do I do this? And is it a `+=` version of this there I can add new arrays of shape `(28,28,1)`  into the existing stack to get `(3,28,28,1)`.

**EDIT**

I have this array of 100 grayscale images: `(100, 784)` which I guess I can reshape to `(100,28,28,1)` with `tf.reshape`.

I want to standardize all pixel values of the 100 images with `tf.image.per_image_standardization` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization)), but this function accepts only input shape `(h,w,ch)` aka. `(28,28,1)`.

Any suggestions on how to optimize this?

**CODE**

```
for i in range(epochs):
    for j in range(samples/batch_size):

        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size) #(100,784)
        batch_xsr = tf.reshape(batch_xs, [-1, 28, 28, 1]) # (100,28,28,1)

        ... 

        #somehow use tf.image.per_image_standardization (input shape = 
        #(28,28,1)) on each of the 100 images, and end up with 
        #shape (100,28,28,1) again.

        ...

        _, loss = sess.run([train, loss_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
```

*Note to self: TensorFlow needs np.array in feed dict.*

Comment: So, you want to take two arrays and if the last 3 elements are similar, then add the first two numbers together (with the default case being 1 if the array size is 3?)

Comment: I would expect that stacking would produce a `(28, 28, 2)`, or maybe `(28, 56, 1)`, or something. Why the _number_ of dimensions grows, as if a Cartesian product is being made?

Comment: @9000, looks like he's using tensorflow (machine learning) and so, `(28, 28, 1)` is probably his heuristics and he probably wants to count them up?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I couldn't really get it to work, so I have updated my question. @ACVM you're right, I'm trying to get a high acc. on mnist.

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: @ascripter code is added.

Comment: edited my answer, try it... just fixed a bug

Comment: Thanks, it actually gave me what I wanted. But TF changes arrays to tf.Tensors so I had to reconstruct some code to get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's functions [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) and [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((28, 28, 1))
B = np.zeros((28, 28, 1))

C = np.stack((A, B), axis=0)

print (C.shape)

>>> (2L, 28L, 28L, 1L)
```

Append further arrays of shape `(28, 28, 1)` to an array of shape `(x, 28, 28, 1)` by concatenating along `axis=0`:

```
D = np.ones((28,28,1))
C = np.concatenate([C, [D]], axis=0)
#C = np.append(C, [D], axis=0)  # equivalent using np.append which is wrapper around np.concatenate

print (C.shape)

>>> (3L, 28L, 28L, 1L)
```

**EDIT**

I'm not familiar with tensorflow, but try this to normalize your images

```
for i in range(epochs):
    for j in range(samples/batch_size):

        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size) #(100,784)
        batch_xsr = tf.reshape(batch_xs, [-1, 28, 28, 1]) # (100,28,28,1)

        for i_image in range(batch_xsr.shape[0]):
            batch_xsr[i_image,:,:,:] = tf.image.per_image_standardization(batch_xsr[i_image,:,:,:])

        _, loss = sess.run([train, loss_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
```

Comment: I like `np.stack`, even though for `axis=0` it behaves the same as `np.array.  I don't like `np.append`.  Too many novices misuse it.  I prefer that they learn to use the underlying `np.concatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I'm not aware how you can "misuse" append. Can you explain?

Comment: Often they expect `np.append` to work just like the list append - in place, and relatively fast.  `np.append`, or for that matter any version of `concatenate` shouldn't be used iteratively.   Another error is to omit the axis, and complain that it ravels the inputs.  You can see from its code that `np.append` doesn't add much to `np.concatenate`.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get it to work with my code, when I print `C.shape` after my for loop has stacked them I get `(100,)`. I have updated my question, maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You could go like this...

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros(shape=(28, 28, 1))
B = np.zeros(shape=(28, 28, 1))
A.shape  # (28, 28, 1)
B.shape  # (28, 28, 1)

C = np.array([A, B])

C.shape  # (2, 28, 28, 1)
```

Then use this to add more, assuming 'new' here is the same shape as A or B.

```
def add_another(C, new):
    return np.array(list(C) + [new])
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't really get it to work, when I print `C.shape` after my for loop has stacked them I get `(100,)`. I have updated my question, maybe there is a better way?